# Buscar un valor dentro de un arreglo PHP

Tags: php

alguien por aquí seguramente a hecho esto antes. quiero buscar un valor dentro de un arreglo, bueno mi estructura es algo tengo dos arreglos asociativos y quiero buscar en uno de ellos,para que se entienda mejor aquí mi código.

```
$personsgroup = array();
    $areagroup = array();
//Primer arreglo con datos que es en el que voy a buscar
 $personsgroup[] = array('correo' => $this->request->data('correo'),
            'password' => $this->_passwordGenerate(),
            'nombres' => $this->request->data('nombres'),
            'apellidos_paternos' => $this->request->data('ape_paterno'),
            'apellidos_maternos' => $this->request->data('ape_materno'),
            'empresa' => $this->request->data('empresa'),
            'nivel' => $this->request->data('nivel'),
            'area' => $this->request->data('area'));
 //Aqui el segundo arreglo se llena de datos
 for($i = 0; $i <= $quantitylevel;$i++){
                        $level = $this->RptNiveles->newEntity();
                        $level->id_nivel = $id_nivel;
                        $level->id_rpt_empresa = $group->id_rpt_empresa;
                        $level->nombre = $areagroup[0]["area"][$i];
                        $this->RptNiveles->save($level);
                        $id_nivel++;
                        //Dentro de esta linea
                        $personsgroupreport[] = array(
                            'id_nivel' => $level->id_nivel,
                            'nombre_nivel' => $level->nombre
                        );
                    }
//Aqui recorro el primer arreglo y que es donde debo realizar la búsqueda con la información que hay dentro del segundo arreglo 
for($p=0;$p <= $groupersons;$p++){
            $persons = $this->Personas->newEntity();
            $persons->id_persona = $id_persons;
            $persons->id_usuario = $id_usuario;
            $persons->id_admin = $id_usuario;
            $persons->usuario = $personsgroup[0]["correo"][$p];
            $persons->password = $personsgroup[0]["password"][$p];
            $persons->nombre = $personsgroup[0]["nombres"][$p];
            $persons->ape_paterno = $personsgroup[0]["apellidos_paternos"][$p];
            $persons->ape_materno = $personsgroup[0]["apellidos_maternos"][$p];
            $persons->nombre_completo = $personsgroup[0]["apellidos_paternos"][$p].' '.$personsgroup[0]["apellidos_maternos"][$p].', '.$personsgroup[0]["nombres"][$p];
            $persons->emp_nombre = $personsgroup[0]["empresa"][$p];
            $this->Personas->save($persons);
            $this->Evaluaciones->InsertEvaluation($persons->id_persona,$id_usuario);
            $id_persons++;

        }
```

Bueno he buscado y php tiene la esta función [Array-search](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php), el tema esta en que esta función devuelve un entero y yo lo que quiero son los valores del arreglo es decir "Clave" => "Valor"

Comment: Jonathan, es decir que en tu busqueda quieres obtener la clave y el valor juntos? Si es asi, no se si un arreglo asociativo sea lo mejor para usar, quizas seria mejor usar matrices o alguna otra estructura.

Answer (score 1):

Imaginemos que buscas el usuario con nombre "Fulanito" en `personsgroup[0]`:

```
$indice = array_search("Fulanito", $personsgroup[0]["nombres"]);
// indice ahora contiene el indice de "Fulanito" en $personsgroup[0]["nombre"]
// Luego puedes acceder los datos usando el indice:
$usuario = $personsgroup[0]["usuario"][$indice];
$password = $personsgroup[0]["password"][$indice];
// ...
```